# SQL update trigger only when column is modified

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

By looking at other examples I've come up with the following but it doesn't seem to work as I would like: I want it to only update the modified information if the `QtyToRepair` value has been updated... but it doesn't do that.

If I comment out the where then the modified information is updated in every case. As I said other examples led me to be optimistic. Any clues appreciated. Thanks.

Walter

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_SCHEDULE_Modified]
   ON [dbo].[SCHEDULE]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE SCHEDULE SET modified = GETDATE()
        , ModifiedUser = SUSER_NAME()
        , ModifiedHost = HOST_NAME()
    FROM SCHEDULE S
    INNER JOIN Inserted I on S.OrderNo = I.OrderNo and S.PartNumber = I.PartNumber
    WHERE S.QtyToRepair <> I.QtyToRepair
END
```

Comment: A warning about `update()` - it only tests if column appears in update list, and is always true for inserts. It does not check if column value has changed, because you might have more than one row, where some values have changed and some have not.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

You have two way for your question :

1- Use Update Command in your Trigger.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_SCHEDULE_Modified]
   ON [dbo].[SCHEDULE]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF UPDATE (QtyToRepair) 
    BEGIN
        UPDATE SCHEDULE 
        SET modified = GETDATE()
           , ModifiedUser = SUSER_NAME()
           , ModifiedHost = HOST_NAME()
        FROM SCHEDULE S INNER JOIN Inserted I 
        ON S.OrderNo = I.OrderNo and S.PartNumber = I.PartNumber
        WHERE S.QtyToRepair <> I.QtyToRepair
    END 
END
```

2- Use Join between Inserted table and deleted table

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_SCHEDULE_Modified]
   ON [dbo].[SCHEDULE]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;    

    UPDATE SCHEDULE 
    SET modified = GETDATE()
       , ModifiedUser = SUSER_NAME()
       , ModifiedHost = HOST_NAME()
    FROM SCHEDULE S 
    INNER JOIN Inserted I ON S.OrderNo = I.OrderNo and S.PartNumber = I.PartNumber
    INNER JOIN Deleted D ON S.OrderNo = D.OrderNo and S.PartNumber = D.PartNumber                  
    WHERE S.QtyToRepair <> I.QtyToRepair
    AND D.QtyToRepair <> I.QtyToRepair
END
```

When you use update command for table `SCHEDULE` and Set `QtyToRepair` Column to new value, if new value equal to old value in one or multi row, solution 1 update all updated row in Schedule table but solution 2 update only schedule rows that old value not equal to new value.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning that it was SQLServer. I needed to use the deleted table. I ended up writing to a separate table (to maintain a history).

Comment: Approach #2 is better, if you don't want your trigger to fire if column is being changed to the same value.

Comment: I think I may be missing something - but approach #1 would not work, because this is *after* the update, so the current row would always have the same value as the inserting row. You *must* join to deleted if you're using after update

Comment: @Rob The "IF UPDATE" statement is invoking a procedure that has access to a column list of columns that were updated as part of the query and thus does not need to know the previous values.  (We just ran into this in our environment and confirmed that "IF UPDATE" is honored regardless of the "AFTER UPDATE" clause)

Comment: why do you join `inserted` table in second query?  it should be the same as table itself, isn't it ?

Comment: Based on the documentation, I'm confused on whether this should be guaranteed to only execute if the field has changed. Some applications such as EntityFramework constantly overwrite every field of a record when a single field may have changed, and I was working when the assumption that this trigger would only be executed if the value had changed. I now don't think that's a safe assumption.

Comment: @Dinerdo - the function `UPDATE(column)` returns true if the column is included in the update statement, _even if the column value remains unchanged_. Using approach #2 compares before & after values of the rows so you can do stuff only if the data values are different. Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/update-trigger-functions-transact-sql

Answer (score 27):

fyi The code I ended up with:

```
IF UPDATE (QtyToRepair)
    begin
        INSERT INTO tmpQtyToRepairChanges (OrderNo, PartNumber, ModifiedDate, ModifiedUser, ModifiedHost, QtyToRepairOld, QtyToRepairNew)
        SELECT S.OrderNo, S.PartNumber, GETDATE(), SUSER_NAME(), HOST_NAME(), D.QtyToRepair, I.QtyToRepair 
        FROM SCHEDULE S
        INNER JOIN Inserted I ON S.OrderNo = I.OrderNo and S.PartNumber = I.PartNumber
        INNER JOIN Deleted D ON S.OrderNo = D.OrderNo and S.PartNumber = D.PartNumber 
        WHERE I.QtyToRepair <> D.QtyToRepair
end
```

Comment: I found this helpful because the **2- Use Join between** answer above never worked due to the where criteria `WHERE S.QtyToRepair <> I.QtyToRepair
    AND D.QtyToRepair <> I.QtyToRepair` never firing / matching as the first criteria was never true - the inserted table always matched the actual table value.

Using ` WHERE I.QtyToRepair <> D.QtyToRepair` was the key for me. Also the `IF UPDATE (field)` help from multiple triggers firing.

Answer (score 14):

One should check if `QtyToRepair` is updated at first.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_SCHEDULE_Modified]
   ON [dbo].[SCHEDULE]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF UPDATE (QtyToRepair) 
    BEGIN
        UPDATE SCHEDULE 
        SET modified = GETDATE()
           , ModifiedUser = SUSER_NAME()
           , ModifiedHost = HOST_NAME()
        FROM SCHEDULE S INNER JOIN Inserted I 
            ON S.OrderNo = I.OrderNo and S.PartNumber =    I.PartNumber
        WHERE S.QtyToRepair <> I.QtyToRepair
    END
END
```

Answer (score 6):

You want to do the following:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_SCHEDULE_Modified]
   ON [dbo].[SCHEDULE]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF (UPDATE(QtyToRepair))
    BEGIN
        UPDATE SCHEDULE SET modified = GETDATE()
            , ModifiedUser = SUSER_NAME()
            , ModifiedHost = HOST_NAME()
        FROM SCHEDULE S
        INNER JOIN Inserted I ON S.OrderNo = I.OrderNo AND S.PartNumber = I.PartNumber
        WHERE S.QtyToRepair <> I.QtyToRepair
    END
END
```

Please note that this trigger will fire each time you update the column no matter if the value is the same or not.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever a record has updated a record is "deleted". Here is my example:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[UpdatePhyDate]
   ON  [dbo].[M_ContractDT1]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- on ContarctDT1 PhyQty is updated 
    -- I want system date in Phytate automatically saved
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    declare @dt1ky as int   

    if(update(Phyqty))
    begin
        select @dt1ky = dt1ky from deleted

        update M_ContractDT1 set PhyDate=GETDATE() where Dt1Ky=  @dt1ky     

    end

END
```

---

It works fine

Comment: It is incorrect because trigger thinks it works with one record but really it works with record set.

Answer (score 0):

'after update' means the table has the inserted data in it when this trigger fires.

Option 2 from the accepted answer is the best route, with one correction in the where clause - not equal to PREVIOUS (deleted) value.

```
WHERE S.QtyToRepair <> D.QtyToRepair
```

accepted answer's option 2, with correction:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_SCHEDULE_Modified]
   ON [dbo].[SCHEDULE]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;    

    UPDATE SCHEDULE 
    SET modified = GETDATE()
       , ModifiedUser = SUSER_NAME()
       , ModifiedHost = HOST_NAME()
    FROM SCHEDULE S 
    INNER JOIN Inserted I ON S.OrderNo = I.OrderNo and S.PartNumber = I.PartNumber
    INNER JOIN Deleted D ON S.OrderNo = D.OrderNo and S.PartNumber = D.PartNumber                  
    WHERE S.QtyToRepair <> D.QtyToRepair
    AND D.QtyToRepair <> I.QtyToRepair
END
```