# MSSQL - trigger to track specific changes in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an Archive and User tables. My goal is to track changes on User table and save old User data to the Archive.

I've mad a trigger but it should also ignore some fields.

For example I have last_login_date so I don't want to create new entry in archive for every user login.

How do I add and track such conditions?

```
CREATE TRIGGER UserUpdateDataTrigger ON Users.[User]
FOR UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @User_id int
    SELECT @User_id = id from inserted

    -- Add an entry to archive
    INSERT INTO 
        Users.Archive (name, email, user_id, user_type) 
    SELECT 
        u.name, u.email, u.id, u.user_type
    FROM 
        Users.[User] u 
    WHERE u.id = @User_id
END
GO
```

My new code:

```
USE [SQL_Tutorial]

IF OBJECT_ID ('Users.UserUpdateDataTrigger', 'TR') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TRIGGER Users.UserUpdateDataTrigger;

GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [Users].[UserUpdateDataTrigger]    Script Date: 2014-10-15 09:34:17 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TRIGGER [Users].[UserUpdateDataTrigger] ON [Users].[User]
FOR UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    -- Add an entry to archive

    IF (UPDATE(name) OR UPDATE(email) OR UPDATE(user_type) OR UPDATE(is_active) OR UPDATE(country_id))

        BEGIN
            DECLARE @User_id int;

            DECLARE @User_name varchar(max);
            DECLARE @User_email varchar(max);
            DECLARE @User_user_type int;
            DECLARE @User_is_active bit;
            DECLARE @User_country_id int;

            SELECT @User_id = id from deleted
            SELECT @User_name = name from deleted
            SELECT @User_email = email from deleted
            SELECT @User_user_type = user_type from deleted
            SELECT @User_is_active = is_active from deleted
            SELECT @User_country_id = country_id from deleted

            INSERT INTO
                Users.Archive (name, email, user_id, user_type, is_active, country_id)
            VALUES
                (@User_name, @User_email, @User_id, @User_user_type, @User_is_active, @User_country_id)
        END

END
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933875(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Is last_login_date field available in Users table? If yes, Do you want to track last_login_date  from users, but without adding a new column in archive table?  Let me know, if i understood correctly..

Comment: This is what you needed, add your columns accordingly.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12137102/sql-update-trigger-only-when-column-is-modified

Comment: `inserted` can contain 0, 1 or *multiple* rows. `SELECT @User_id = id from inserted` is fundamentally flawed.

Comment: Damien so I should declare each field individually and then based on field changes insert new data? If I understand correctly I did 'SELECT @User_id = id from inserted' is the wrong, lazy way ;)?

Comment: Venkat G - last_login_date is available in Users table and I don't want to track last_login_date - I want to ignore change for that field in that table.

Comment: @Efrin - no, you should use `inserted` in the `FROM` clause of a query that recognizes that it's working with multiple rows - at the moment, you're getting the `id` from *one* of the rows (which one is undefined) and *ignoring* the other rows.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the lsat entry for the user in the archive, and then see if any fields changed.  The basic query is:

```
with aui as (
      select au.*, row_number() over (partition by user_id order by achive_id desc) as seqnum,
             i.name as i_name, i.email as i_email, i.user_type as i.user_type
      from user.archive au join
           inserted i
           on u.user_id = i.user_id
     )
insert into users.archive(name, email, user_id, user_type)
    select name, email, user_id, user_type
    from aui
    where seqnum = 1 and
          (i_name <> name or i_email <> email or i_user_type <> user_type)
```

Two notes.  First, this assumes that you have an identity column in `archive` so you can find the last inserted row for a given user.  For your logic, this is quite important.  Second, the above logic doesn't handle `NULL` values, although a slight modification to the `where` clause can fix that.