# Is "IF NOT UPDATE(column)" valid syntax?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

If within a Sql Server trigger I want to test if a column was *not* included in the `UPDATE` statement, is

```
IF NOT UPDATE(column)
```

the correct syntax? I've read a much older discussion suggesting this might not also work and one should use an `IF UPDATE(column)...ELSE` syntax, except I would not have any relevant statement to add for the first condition.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL update trigger only when column is modified](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12137102/sql-update-trigger-only-when-column-is-modified)

Comment: Working here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a0ce2/1

Comment: Check document at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187326.aspx

Comment: Not sure why my question would be considered a duplicate. I very clearly state I want to test when a column is **not** updated. The suggested duplicate is about testing when a column is modified. Yes, I have looked at  BOL, as I always do. It's not clear how to test the negative, or if `UPDATE()` was not intended to be used as a negative.

Comment: @NoDisplayName Thank you! Your example answers my question. I did not think of using a `PRINT` statement for testing. If you post a quick answer, I will mark it accepted, otherwise I will answer it myself, for the record.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax `IF NOT UPDATE(column)` is correct and can be verified by the following simple test, as @NoDisplayName pointed out:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test(Id int, Foo int);
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.Test VALUES (1, 1);
GO

CREATE TRIGGER TestTrigger ON dbo.Test
AFTER UPDATE
AS
IF NOT UPDATE(Foo)
  PRINT 'Foo Not Included In Update Statement';
IF UPDATE(Id)
  PRINT 'Id Included In Update Statement';
GO

UPDATE dbo.Test SET Id = 1;

/*
output:
Foo Not Included In Update Statement
Id Included In Update Statement
*/
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't have a server to check this on right now, but this is how you can list the rows in an update where "columnToCheck" was not changed.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgMyTrigger ON [dbo].[myTable] 
AFTER UPDATE
AS

    SELECT
    *
    FROM inserted AS i
    INNER JOIN deleted AS d ON i.ID = d.ID
    WHERE i.columnToCheck = d.columnToCheck

GO
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to check for 'not changed'. I want to check for the column not being included in the UPDATE statement at all. As @NoDisplayName demonstrated, `IF NOT UPDATE(column)` is, in fact, valid syntax.