# Using an UPDATE trigger to notify me when a table is updated in a database

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

Here is the code I already have. I just want to simply send an email to a certain address when data in the Area column has been updated.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Update_Trigger]  
ON [dbo].[tablename]
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
    IF UPDATE(Area)
    BEGIN
         EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
            @profile_name = 'example'
            @recipients = 'email@example.com'
            @body = 'An area has changed'
            @subject = 'The Area records have been changed'
    END;
GO
```

I'm probably doing something stupid wrong so any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Please let us know what is the error / issue you're facing

Comment: If it's a syntax problem you have, you might also be missing a 'BEGIN' tag after the first 'AS' on line4. Refer this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12137102/sql-update-trigger-only-when-column-is-modified

Comment: @pkamathk - No, It is a valid syntax in `SQL Server`

Answer (score 1):

You are missing *comma* between `Sp_send_dbmail` procedure parameter's

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Update_Trigger]
ON [dbo].[tablename]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
    IF UPDATE([Area])
      BEGIN
          EXEC msdb.dbo.Sp_send_dbmail
            @profile_name = 'example', --Here
            @recipients = 'email@example.com', --Here
            @body = 'An area has changed', --Here
            @subject = 'The Area records have been changed'
      END;

GO
```

Make sure the following setting's are made before using `Sp_send_dbmail`,

1. `Example` profile is created
2. Database Mail must be enabled using the Database Mail Configuration Wizard, or `sp_configure`.

To configure run the below code

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Database Mail XPs', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
```