# Using IF UPDATE on SQL Trigger when handling multiple inserted/updated records

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I use this SQL Server trigger to look for insert/update of multiple records from a specific table and put it into another queue table (for processing later).

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[IC_ProductUpdate] ON [dbo].[StockItem]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ItemID) , ItemID
    INTO #ProductUpdates
    FROM INSERTED;

    DECLARE @MaxRownum INT;
    SET @MaxRownum = (SELECT MAX(RowNum) FROM #ProductUpdates);

    DECLARE @Iter INT;
    SET @Iter = (SELECT MIN(RowNum) FROM #ProductUpdates);

    WHILE @Iter <= @MaxRownum
    BEGIN
        -- Get Product Id
        DECLARE @StockItemID INT = (SELECT ItemID FROM #ProductUpdates WHERE RowNum = @Iter);

        -- Proceed If This Product Is Sync-able
        IF (dbo.IC_CanSyncProduct(@StockItemID) = 1)
        BEGIN
            -- Check If There Is A [ProductUpdate] Queue Entry Already Exist For This Product
            IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM IC_ProductUpdateQueue WHERE StockItemID = @StockItemID) > 0)
            BEGIN
                -- Reset [ProductUpdate] Queue Entry
                UPDATE IC_ProductUpdateQueue 
                SET Synced = 0
                WHERE StockItemID = @StockItemID
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                -- Insert [ProductUpdate] Queue Entry
                INSERT INTO IC_ProductUpdateQueue (StockItemID, Synced) 
                VALUES (@StockItemID, 0)
            END
        END

        SET @Iter = @Iter + 1;
    END

    DROP TABLE #ProductUpdates;
END
```

This works fine, however I only want the above trigger to react if certain columns were updated.

The columns I am interested in are:

- Name
- Description

I know I can use the following T-SQL syntax to check if a column really updated (during update event) like this:

```
IF (UPDATE(Name) OR UPDATE(Description))
BEGIN
    // do something...
END
```

But, I am not sure how to incorporate this into the above trigger, since my trigger handles multiple rows being updated at same time also.

Any ideas? At which point in the trigger could i use `IF (UPDATE(colX))`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL update trigger only when column is modified](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12137102/sql-update-trigger-only-when-column-is-modified)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would suggest to have *one separate* trigger for each operation - one for `INSERT`, and another for `UPDATE`. Keeps the code cleaner (less messy *IF* statements and so forth).

The `INSERT` trigger is pretty simple, since there's nothing to check for updating - and there's absolutely no need for a temporary table and a slow `WHILE` loop - just two simple, set-based statements and you're done:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[IC_ProductInsert] ON [dbo].[StockItem]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    -- update the queue for those entries that already exist                 
    -- those rows that *DO NOT* exist yet are not being touched
    UPDATE puq
    SET Synced = 0
    FROM dbo.IC_ProductUpdateQueue puq
    INNER JOIN Inserted i ON puq.StockItemID = i.StockItemID

    -- for those rows that don't exist yet - insert the values
    INSERT INTO dbo.IC_ProductUpdateQueue (StockItemID, Synced) 
        SELECT 
            i.StockItemID, 0
        FROM
            Inserted i
        WHERE 
            NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.IC_ProductUpdateQueue puq
                        WHERE puq.StockItemID = i.StockItemID)
END
```

The `UPDATE` trigger needs one extra check - to see whether or not one of the two columns of interest has changed. This can be handled quite easily by combining the `Inserted` pseudo table with the new values (after the `UPDATE`), and the `Deleted` pseudo table with the "old" values (before the `UPDATE`):

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[IC_ProductUpdate] ON [dbo].[StockItem]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    -- update the queue for those entries that already exist                 
    -- those rows that *DO NOT* exist yet are not being touched
    UPDATE puq
    SET Synced = 0
    FROM dbo.IC_ProductUpdateQueue puq
    INNER JOIN Inserted i ON puq.StockItemID = i.StockItemID
    INNER JOIN Deleted d ON d.StockItemID = i.StockItemID
    WHERE
        i.Name <> d.Name OR i.Description <> d.Description

    -- for those rows that don't exist yet - insert the values
    INSERT INTO dbo.IC_ProductUpdateQueue (StockItemID, Synced) 
        SELECT 
            i.StockItemID, 0
        FROM
            Inserted i
        INNER JOIN 
            Deleted d ON d.StockItemID = i.StockItemID
        WHERE 
            i.Name <> d.Name OR i.Description <> d.Description
            AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.IC_ProductUpdateQueue puq
                            WHERE puq.StockItemID = i.StockItemID)
END
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for and appreciate the information.  I would like to add for the sake of others that the join to deleted represents the "old" values prior to update and no records are actually deleted.

Answer (score 1):

You can join to deleted and use where I.Name <> D.Name...

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2342/understanding-sql-server-inserted-and-deleted-tables-for-dml-triggers/