# Find modified fields in Update Trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

What would be the simplest way to get a list of all the modified fields in an `Update Trigger`?

The most compact way I could think of, was to do something of the type:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM INSERTED INNER JOIN DELETED ON INSERTED.[FIELD_TO_CHECK] = DELETE.[FIELD_TO_CHECK])
```

But that would mean I would have to do this for every field I would want to check. I would appreciate an approach with a `cursor` containing information about all the modified fields.

(This doesn't need to work for mass-updates, Don't need to expect more than 1 record in `INSERTED` OR `DELETED`)

I've added an if statement to ignore mass updates, since they fall under a different category.

Comment: "Don't need to expect more than 1 record in INSERTED OR DELETED" until you do get that... It's better to not assume such assumptions.

Comment: What is your actual goal here when you find out what columsn have been updated? If it simply to log the old values, then normally you just log the whole row in entirety regards of if 1 or 100 columns have been updated. Otherwise, possibly a duplciate of [SQL update trigger only when column is modified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12137102/sql-update-trigger-only-when-column-is-modified)?

Comment: If you don't expect to get multiple rows and you don't intend to handle multiple rows correctly, then your trigger should enforce this assumption by throwing an error when multiple rows are encountered. Why? Because it will happen some day.

Comment: If you want an approach with a CURSOR why don't you just write one?

Comment: @TabAlleman I was asking if there is any way I can select all the modified fields with a cursor and do a specific action for each one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I'm not aware of any reliable built-in function that can give you an indication if the value of a column actually changed when an update statement fired a trigger.

However, there is pretty simple select statement you can execute to see what values have changed in what rows:

```
SELECT IIF(ISNULL(NULLIF(I.Col, D.Col), NULLIF(D.Col, I.Col)) IS NULL, 0, 1) As Col_Updated
FROM Inserted I
JOIN Deleted D
    ON I.PrimaryKey = D.PrimaryKey
```

The `NULLIF` function will return `null` if both columns are equal. If not, it returns the value of the first column.

The `ISNULL` function will return the first argument that is not `null`, or `null` if both arguments are null.

Using `ISNULL` on the result of two `NULLIF` functions where the column values are reversed will result in `null` if the values of both columns are the same, even if they both are null. If the values are different, even if one of them is null and the other is not, then `ISNULL` will return a value. Therefor, all you have to do is check if the `ISNULL` returned a value or null - if it return `null`, you know the column's value was not changed. If it returns a value, then it is changed.

Of course, for non-nullable columns you can simplify the condition like this:

```
SELECT IIF(I.Col <> D.Col, 1, 0) As Col_Updated
FROM...
```

However I would recommend **against** that, since if someone will change the column to allow null, the trigger code will have to change to support that - and in my experience, that's a bug waiting to happen - trigger code will probably not be changed, leading to false-negatives.

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](https://rextester.com/CRNK54065)

**Update**
Another simple method you can use is this:

```
IIF((I.Col IS NULL AND D.Col IS NULL) OR (I.Col = D.Col), 0, 1) as IsUpdated.
```

This method relies on the fact that comparing null to anything else will result with `unknown` which is basically equivalent to `false`.

It's slightly more readable IMHO.