# SQL Trigger on Update - Certain Table Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-update

I need to set up a trigger that will update a modified date, to the current date and time, but only if the user name or password are changed. Those are the 4th and 5th columns.

I used the tips from this thread to try to make a trigger. For now I just wanted to fill a log table, so I could test that it's working correctly. Eventually, I would turn the insert into logs into the update statement, for updating the modified date: [SQL update trigger only when column is modified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12137102/sql-update-trigger-only-when-column-is-modified)

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.updUserData 
ON tblUserInfo
AFTER UPDATE 
AS  
    DECLARE @USR VARCHAR(8000)
    DECLARE @PW VARCHAR(8000)

    IF (COLUMNS_UPDATED() & 25) > 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @USR = UI.UserName 
        FROM .[dbo].[tblUserInfo] UI
        INNER JOIN Inserted I ON UI.ID = I.ID 
        WHERE UI.UserName <> I.UserName

        SELECT @PW = EC.Password 
        FROM [dbo].[tblUserInfo] UI
        INNER JOIN Inserted I ON UI.ID = I.ID 
        WHERE UI.Password <> I.Password

        INSERT INTO logs
        VALUES ('USERNAME ' + @USR + 'OR PASSWORD CHANGED ' + @Pw) 
    END
```

When I modify THE 4th or 5th column, I get a new record in the logs table, but the string is NULL. It's not inserting the string, but it is limiting to creating the NULL record only when one of those 2 columns are changed.  That is enough for me to know it's capturing the right activity, but I wanted to see if I could get this to work and insert the actual string into the logs table, as I thought it would be a good exercise for me to get right.

If anyone can help me get this across the finish line, I'd love the help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `insert . . . select`?

```
INSERT INTO logs (<name the column here>)
    SELECT 'USERNAME ' + i.username + 'OR PASSWORD CHANGED ' + i.password
    FROM inserted i JOIN
         deleted d
         ON i.id = d.id
    WHERE i.username <> d.username OR
          i.password <> d.password;
```

Comment: That's not giving me any insert at all, let alone a null. Not sure why.

Comment: I got it! INSERT INTO logs (logstring)
SELECT 'UserName ' + i.UserName + ' Password ' + i.Password +' Mod By ' + SUSER_SNAME() + ' DATE TIME ' + CAST (GETDATE() AS VARCHAR)
FROM tblUserInfo ui
INNER JOIN INSERTED i ON ui.id = i.ID

Comment: Thanks for your help!